# Understanding desc.fields

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7

First time poster so I hope I did this right.
I'm relatively new to Python scripting and am trying to understand the error I'm getting.

I have the following simple code and what I don't understand is why PAD_HI_250extent generates the *Method fields does not exist* error?  They are both polygon feature classes stored in the same file gdb.  Is there a difference in the two feature classes that I'm not aware of?  Can the content of the fields, as opposed to the field name themselves, affect this (I do know that there are special characters, e.g.,  K'au Forest Reserve)

Running ArcMap 10.1 on Win7, Python 2.7.2

```
=================================================================================
SCRIPT
======
import arcpy, time

## set environment settings
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"F:\USER\FLATHER\TE_AtRisk_grid_model\FeatureClasses.gdb"

files = ["BOC_HI_BG_250extent", "PAD_HI_250extent"]

for file in files:
    print 'File:', file
    desc = arcpy.Describe(file)
    fieldnames = [f.name for f in desc.fields if f.type not in ["Geometry", "Raster", "Blob"]]
    print fieldnames
    print ' '

==================================================================================
OUTPUT
======
File: BOC_HI_BG_250extent
[u'OBJECTID', u'FID_HI_fishnet_250sqmi', u'FID_BOC_HI_BlockGroups', u'STATEFP', u'COUNTYFP', u'TRACTCE', u'BLKGRPCE', u'GEOID', u'NAMELSAD', u'MTFCC', u'FUNCSTAT', u'ALAND', u'AWATER', u'INTPTLAT', u'INTPTLON', u'Shape_Length', u'Shape_Area', u'tot_area', u'fishnetID']

File: PAD_HI_250extent

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/USER/FLATHER/TE_AtRisk_grid_model/scripts/DDD_descfields.py", line 15, in <module>
    fieldnames = [f.name for f in desc.fields if f.type not in ["Geometry", "Raster", "Blob"]]
AttributeError: DescribeData: Method fields does not exist
>>>
```

Comment: it might be helpful to print out desc.dataType (after the line desc = arcpy.Describe(file)) just to verify the feature class is what you think it is. You might also try the ListFields function on that feature class and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Describe` function is well documented at [ArcGIS Resource Center](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Describe/03q30000008q000000/). It is a quit big topic to define in here. So, have a look at the given link.

In your case, the item `"PAD_HI_250extent"` doesn't have `fields`. As pointed by  [MWrenn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/1777/mwrenn) above. It is wise to check the `desc` type first before calling its properties.